# What are the key differences between Hytera DMR and MotoTRBO?

Tags: dmr

What I'm really curious about is if anyone can provide a high level overview of the two technologies. I know that they are both utilizing the DMR standard, but from what I have read is that the way which the repeaters signal radios is slightly different.

For example, I have read that Motorola requires each talkgroup to be given a specific time-slot whereas Hytera does not do this and intelligently assigns time-slot allocation based on availability. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: "I have read": where? In such cases, it's usually helpful to say what your source is, so that we might be able to read it ourselves, and contextualize what you say they claim.

Comment: I've tried finding this article again but to no avail. Essentially, it stated that time slots were programmed at the radio level on a Motorola system. In trying to find that article again though, I really can't find any good material that states exactly how the MotoTRBO system decides what timeslot to use and when to use it.